# Move a Shape to the next Slide with VBA (PPT)

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

First of all I'm new to VBA.

I would like to go to move a shape from one slide to the following slide. And I want to do it for each slide of the presentation. (in edit mode)

```
        Dim Sld As Slide
        Dim Shp As Shape

    For Each Sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

        For Each Shp In Sld.Shapes
            With Shp
                If .Type = msoAutoShape _
                    And .Left = 715 _
                    And .Top = 366 _
                    Then
/!\ In the next slide /!\
                        .Left = 50 'change the number for desired x position
                        .Top = 50 'change the number for desired y position
                End If
            End With
        Next 'Shape
    Next Sld   ' Slide
```

this is the code I have so far. It is working to move shapes inside the same slide, but I don't really know what to add move the shape in the next slide.

Thank you in advancefor your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little snippet that should help:

```
' Copy the shape to the clipboard:
Shp.Copy

' Paste the shape to the next slide
' Shp.Parent gives you a reference to the slide the shape is on
' Shp.Parent.SlideIndex + 1 gives you a reference to the NEXT slide
ActivePresentation.Slides(Shp.Parent.SlideIndex + 1).Shapes.Paste

' And delete the original shape
Shp.Delete
```

You'll need to make sure that there really IS a next slide, of course.  ActivePresentation.Slides.Count will tell you how many slides there are.